# How can use php code inside selected in option?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I include selected condition inside the first option in php? I am
not getting the way please help me related this.

```
<select class="form-control search_form_display" id="type" name="type" disabled="">
     <option value="">----Please Select----</option>
     <?php 
     if ($category['res']) {
         foreach($category['rows'] as $row) { 
             echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->c_name.'</option>';
         }
     } else {
          echo '<option value="">No Active Category</option>';
     }
     ?>
</select>
```

I want to include this inside the selected tag:

```
<?php if($this->input->get('searchby')=='1') { echo "selected"; } ?>
```

Comment: you want to get selected first option only.?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may help you...thanks!

```
<?php $selected = '';

if($this->input->get('searchby')=='1'){  $selected = "selected";} ?>


<select class="form-control search_form_display" id="type" name="type" disabled="">
     <option value="">----Please Select----</option>
     <?php 
     if($category['res']){
     foreach($category['rows'] as $row)
     { 
     echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'" '.$selected'>'.$row->c_name.'</option>';
     }
      }else{
     echo '<option value="">No Active Category</option>';
     }
     ?>
    </select>
```

Comment: $this->input->get('searchby')=='1' here searchby would be dynamic value passed by url..

Comment: yeah...i understood that...but why u check that is equal to '1' ??

Answer (score 0):

if you are using codeigniter just use their form helper function

```
$selected = $this->input->get('searchby');
echo form_dropdown('type', $options_array, $selected);
```

you can prepare your $options_array however you prefer

e.g.

```
$options_array = array(
   '' => ' --- Please Select' 
);

foreach($category['rows'] as $row) {
  $options_array[$row->id] = $row->c_name;
}
```

Update:

```
$select_selected =  ($this->input->get('searchby')=='1') ? "selected" : "";

echo form_dropdown('type', $options_array, $selected, $select_selected);
```

I haven't tested the above code but I think it should help you get what you want. The fourth param in form_dropdown() is for adding any extra attributes to the select tag itself. If you just want to select any option by value passed by url, just provide it as 3rd param to select that option.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html?highlight=form_dropdown#form_dropdown

Comment: <?php if($this->input->get('searchby')=='1'){echo "selected";} ?>

i want to add this inside the selected tag in php

Comment: `<option <?php echo $this->input->get('searchby') ? 'selected="selected" ? '';?>>` should do the job.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'searchby' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'  returning this error

Answer (score 0):

You have tow options

1. Remove the  `'<option value="">----Please Select----</option>'`;
   valid only for selected first option.
2. Follow the code

   ```
   <select class="form-control search_form_display" id="type" name="type" disabled="">
   <option value="">----Please Select----</option>
   <?php 
   if($category['res']){$i=1;
       foreach($category['rows'] as $row){
           echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'"';
           if($i==1){ echo 'selected="selected"';$i=0;}//select 1st option
           echo '>'.$row->c_name.'</option>';}
   }
   else{echo '<option value="">No Active Category</option>';}
   ?>
   </select>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

example :

```
<?php  
$lang_id =1;
$array = array(array('language'=>'php','id'=>1),
array('language'=>'c#','id'=>2)); ?>

<select name="language" id="lang">
<option value=0> Select the Language </option>
<?php foreach($array as $arr){ ?>
<option value="<?php echo $arr['id']; ?>" 
<?php if($lang_id==$arr['id']) echo 'selected'; ?>> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>

 output : php is selected option
```